# Why does this multithreaded multiconnection TCP server only accept one connection?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, tcp

**story behind all of this**

I'm trying to write an open source RPG inventory server, usable for more than 1 RPG at once, and will make a game for it later on. My first version doesn't support a lot of security or encryption. But I'd like to have a solid start.

**Problem**

It does accept one connection, drop in drop out. But my implementation of threading only seems to accept one connection. Is someone who can give me a guideline on how to do this properly? I've commented the code I will supply for your reading ease.

**Setup**
I use visual studio 2010 with SP1 enabled. I only tried it within my home network so IP forwarding is not needed. It accepts both PC's separately.

A lot of thanks to the ones helping, if you help and want to be credited in the end result just let me know. and if someone has general comments I'd love to hear them;)

EDIT: it has something to do with the NewIPEP() method.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace TCPServer1
{

class ServerV1
{
    static int maxthreads = 4;
    static bool[] threadavailable = new bool[maxthreads];
    static Thread[] listenThread = new Thread[maxthreads];
    static IPEndPoint[] ipep = new IPEndPoint[maxthreads];
    static bool[] threadconnected = new bool[maxthreads];
    static Socket[] newsock = new Socket[maxthreads];
    static Socket[] client = new Socket[maxthreads];
    static ItemListClassV1 parent;
    static Login loginin;
    static ProtoColV1[] protocol = new ProtoColV1[maxthreads];
    /// <summary>
    /// initialises variables and starts a first thread.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    public ServerV1(ItemListClassV1 parentid, Login login)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxthreads; i++)
        {
            threadavailable[i] = true;
        }
        parent = parentid;
        loginin = login;
        StartThread();

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// should be split but handles the servershit look further for seperate "method" comments
    /// </summary>
    static void Server()
    {

        int recv = 0;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];



        //looks for incoming connections
        ipep[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)] = NewIPEP();

        newsock[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)] = new
            Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        newsock[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Bind(ipep[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)]);
        newsock[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Listen(10);
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");
        client[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)] = newsock[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Accept();

        //if connected
        IPEndPoint clientep =
                     (IPEndPoint)client[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].RemoteEndPoint;
        Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}",
                        clientep.Address, clientep.Port);


        //if connection start a new thread
        StartThread();

        //send welcome message to client
        string welcome = "Welcome to my test server";
        data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
        client[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Send(data, data.Length,
                          SocketFlags.None);


        while (true)//this looks for incoming data and sends reply.
        {
            try
            {

                data = new byte[1024];
                recv = client[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Receive(data);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                if (e != null)
                    break;
            }
            if (client[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Connected != true)//when not connected break the loop
            {
                break;
            }


            ////EXECUTES moet wer trug
            //byte[][] packets = protocol[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Execute(data,recv);//EXECUTES THE DATA EXTERNALLY
            byte[][] packets = new byte[1][];
                packets[0] = data;

            for (int i = 0; i < packets.Length; i++)//stuurt vervolgens alle pakketjes
            {
                client[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Send(packets[i], packets[i].Length,
                              SocketFlags.None);
            }

        }


        //when not connected this continues 
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from {0}",
                          clientep.Address);

        //close socket
        client[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Close();
        newsock[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Close();


        bool full = true;
        //if the server was full now a slot opened 
        for (int l = 0; l < maxthreads; l++)
        {
            if (threadavailable[l])
            {
                full = false;
            }
            if (!threadavailable[l] && !threadconnected[l])
            {
                full = false;
            }
        }

        //closes thread, deletes information
        threadavailable[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)] = true;
        ipep[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)] = null;
        protocol[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)] = null;


        if (full)
        {
            StartThread();
        }

        //stops thread
        listenThread[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)] = null;
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();



    }

    /// <summary>
    /// keeps searching for incoming connections and returns the found connection when found.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static IPEndPoint NewIPEP()
    {

        IPEndPoint temp = null;
        bool newconnection = false;
        while (!newconnection)
        {
            temp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);

            for (int k = 0; k < maxthreads; k++)
            {
                if (!threadavailable[k] && ipep[k] != null && ipep[k].Address != null )
                {
                    if (temp.Address == ipep[k].Address)
                    {
                        k = maxthreads;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (k == maxthreads - 1)
                {
                    newconnection = true;
                    threadconnected[Convert.ToInt32(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Name)] = true;
                }
            }

        }
        return temp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// finds the first unstarted thread and starts it
    /// </summary>
    static void StartThread()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxthreads; i++)
        {
            if (threadavailable[i])
            {

                threadavailable[i] = false;
                threadconnected[i] = false;
                protocol[i] = new ProtoColV1(parent,loginin);
                listenThread[i] = new Thread(Server);
                listenThread[i].Name = Convert.ToString(i);
                listenThread[i].Start();
                break;

            }
        }
    }





}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please refrain from using tags in titles.  We have *real* tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only called `Socket client = newsock.Accept();` once, that's why only one client is accepted.

Comment: Unfortunate that didnt work. Did correct it though because you were right. The waiting for a client message also doesnt pop up a second time. so i think theres something wrong with the threading? Thanks though (:

Comment: In the end it had to do with the newIPEP method. I did make some mistakes on the newsock place due to a lack of understanding. it works now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I dont know how to add comments... Have you checked out Lidgren? Why re-invent the wheel? 
http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/

He has same great examples on how to use the library.

Good luck!

Linuxx

Comment: Sounds really good, but i would prefer data security so i'd like to use TCP for now. Will look at this for future versions!

Comment: It has encryption built in. http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/wiki/MessageEncryption

Comment: yeah but i'm not focussing yet on building encryptio, but building a stable basic system to be able to test a game on. if i want my data encrypted ill prob use it.

Comment: Everything you are trying to do is already done with Lidgren. It would take you 10 lines of code, and 10 minutes to do this. Lidgren does reliable UDP, Encryption, sessions, multi-threading, etc.

Comment: will use it in the next version prob